# Rendering HTML from textarea to div without affecting entire browser background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my web page, I have two boxes that take up roughly half the width of the screen. The left box is a textarea for writing HTML, the right is a div where the HTML is rendered into as if it were a separate web page. The issue I'm having is that, if someone writes HTML in the textarea and they write CSS for the `body` element (like background-color), rendering it into the div affects the background of the entire website and not the div, which I would like. I've looked around and have gained an understanding of why the browser behaves this way, but I'm wondering if there's a way to work around it.

Can I, before rendering the textarea's HMTL into the div, search through the textarea and replace any instance of `<body>` with `<div>` and `</body>` with `</div>`? This way it would only affect the div and not the entire website.

My function that renders HTML is this:

```
// click 'showmeImg' to render the contents of 'editor' into the 'outputContainer'
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#showmeImg").click(function(){
                $("#outputContainer").html($(editor.getValue()));
            });
        });
```

For instance, if someone types this into the textarea:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="background-color: blue;">
    --Other HTML code--
</body>
</html>
```

Clicking showmeImg changes the background of the entire web page, and not 'outputContainer'. So ideally, I'd like to have a function that changes the above code to:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<div style="background-color: blue;">
    --Other HTML code--
</div>
</html>
```

before my function renders it into the div.

Comment: place it in an `<iframe>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Comment: I was thinking of doing that, but I can't seem to figure out how to change my rendering function to affect an iframe. If I just change the tag of outputContainer to iframe, the function no longer works.

Comment: no im saying take the whole string from your textarea and send it to your iframe page that you made separately to receive it with an event handler that renders the HTML that's passed through using `window.postMessage`